# Need OpenCL library for cpp-ethereum on Alpine

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I am trying to build `cpp-ethereum` on Alpine, and I quickly discovered that I don't have quite the same set of libraries available via `apk` that I have on Ubuntu via `apt-get`.  I have built `leveldb`, `cryptopp`, `libjson-rpc-cpp`, and `miniupmpc` from source without any problem.  However, I've run into a problem with OpenCL sources.  There is a sweet little installation script that usually does everything I need, but the script depends on `ldconfig` working the same way on Alpine as it does on Ubuntu/Debian.  There is no `ldconfig -p` on Alpine, `ldconfig` requires a target, and the default target on Ubuntu doesn't even exist on Alpine.  Has anyone resolved this successfully and built `cpp-ethereum` on Alpine?